# What is known about the coefficients of high powers of the Vandermonde determinant?

Tags: polynomials, asymptotics

This question is about high powers (parameter $p$ going to infinity) of the Vandermonde determinant with $N$ entries, for fixed $N$. I expand
$$
\Delta(X_1, \dots, X_N)^p = \prod_{i < j} (X_i - X_j)^p = \sum_{u_1+\dots+u_N=\mu} a_{(u_1, \dots, u_N)}^{N,p} X_1^{u_1} \dots X_N^{u_N}
$$
where the sum is taken over all integer partitions of $\mu = p \frac{N (N-1)}{2}$.

I couldn't find any known results, neither exact nor asymptotics, about the coefficients $a_{(u_1, \dots, u_N)}^{N,p}$. The case $N=2$ is simple; for $N=3$ already, things are getting messier.

Is there a way to characterize where the larger of these coefficients will be, how large exactly they are, where they are very small or cancel, etc. ?

Comment: here is a closed form expression for these coefficients, and more info with pointers to the literature: https://mathoverflow.net/a/233068/11260

Comment: Another reference is Chapter 12 of Gelfand, Kapranov, and Zelevinsky, http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/gelkapzel.pdf,

Comment: Thank you guys ! I hadn't seen the previous post; it is only about one of these coefficients, but it is already something.

Comment: @RichardStanley: GKZ seems to do the expansion in the $e_{\lambda}$ basis, whereas the OP's question is about the $m_{\lambda}$ basis, at least if $p$ is even.